# データの補間を行って対応する値を出力したい

Tags: python, python3

Yの任意の値に対して線形補間を行い下のデータにない値でもXの値が返ってくるようにしたいです。
例えばYが0.3のときのXの値を求める。

```
X=[0.01 0.1  0.5  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.  ]
Y=[0.043675 0.041689 0.033546 0.027305 0.020843 0.016325 0.014061 0.012296　0.011067 0.010214]
```

以下の画像は上のデータをプロットしたものです。

[image]

①は画像を出力したコードです。
②は自分なりに調べて補間を行いましたが、求めたい結果をうまく得ることができませんでした。

①

```
plt.scatter(LAI,toc_red)
plt.plot(LAI,toc_red)
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel('Y')
```

②

```
x_latent = np.linspace(min(LAI), max(LAI), 100)
from scipy import interpolate
ip= ["線形補間", interpolate.interp1d]

for method_name, method in [ip]:
    print(method_name)
    fitted_curve = method(LAI, toc_red)
    plt.scatter(LAI, toc_red, label="observed")
    plt.plot(x_latent, fitted_curve(x_latent), c="red", label="fitted")
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scipyの`interpolate.interp1d`が正に解決方法です。
線形補間した新たな関数`f_1d`を作成し、`y=f_1d(x)`のようにして補間値を求めます。

```python
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

X = [0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., ]
Y = [0.043675, 0.041689, 0.033546, 0.027305, 0.020843, 0.016325, 0.014061, 0.012296, 0.011067, 0.010214]

f_1d = interp1d(X, Y)
y = f_1d(0.3)
print(float(y))
# => 0.0376175
```